# Performance down

Tags: c, performance

Can anyone help me with this?

```
void _vect_mat(float *vect,float **mat){
  float temp[4];

  temp[0] = vect[0];
  temp[1] = vect[1];
  temp[2] = vect[2];
  temp[3] = vect[3];

  vect[0] = (temp[0] * mat[0][0]) + (temp[1] * mat[1][0]) + (temp[2] * mat[2][0]) + (temp[3] * mat[3][0]);
  vect[1] = (temp[0] * mat[0][1]) + (temp[1] * mat[1][1]) + (temp[2] * mat[2][1]) + (temp[3] * mat[3][1]);
  vect[2] = (temp[0] * mat[0][2]) + (temp[1] * mat[1][2]) + (temp[2] * mat[2][2]) + (temp[3] * mat[3][2]);
  vect[3] = (temp[0] * mat[0][3]) + (temp[1] * mat[1][3]) + (temp[2] * mat[2][3]) + (temp[3] * mat[3][3]);
}

int main(){
  int i,j,k;

  float *vect,**mat;

  vect =  (float *)malloc(4 * sizeof(float));
  mat  = (float **)malloc(4 * sizeof(float *);
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)mat[i] = (float *)malloc(4 * sizeof(float));

  vect[0] = 1.0;
  vect[n] = ......etc.

  mat[0][0] = 1.0;
  mat[n][m] ......etc.     

  while (1){
    for(i = 0;i < 5;i++){
      for(j = 0;j< 6;j++){
        for(k = 0;k < 3600;k++)_vect_mat(vect,mat); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I call the function `_vect_mat` inside the loop, all performance falls. It is Normal?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try whether it's faster with `float vect[4], mat[4][4];`. If the sizes are actually large, you should still allocate the matrix as a contiguous block for better locality, `float (*mat)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof *mat);`.

Comment: What does "all performance fails" mean? You have an infinite loop there, how do you measure performance?

Comment: Well, This in only a part of a program made with OpenGL. The FPS count is 12. But without the function the FPS count is 75 (my refresh rate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is you say `float **mat`. That means fetching elements like `mat[1][2]` is a two-step process. First it has to fetch `mat[1]` as a pointer, and then it has to fetch element `[2]` from that.

If instead you declare `float mat[16]`, and index directly into that, for example `mat[1 + 2*4]` the fetching of those elements will be maybe twice as fast.